# Is it possible in VIM to delimit an external (bash) command?

Tags: vim

Given the following

1. I want to write a file
2. Change to the directory of the file
3. Execute a bash command
4. change to the previous directory

I made the following command

```
command Asc execute ":w | :cd %:p:h | !ansible-playbook --syntax-check % "
```

This seems to be working so far. However changing back to the previous directory with `:cd -` does not seem to work.

```
command Asc execute ":w | :cd %:p:h | !ansible-playbook --syntax-check % | :cd -"
```

My guess is, that the pipe and the stuff followed is interpreted by bash and not by vim.

How to overcome this problem? Or is there no way at all?

P.S.: I am aware of the autochdir option of vim

Comment: Also checkout out [vi.se], for Vim-focused questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`:h :!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd):

```
A '|' in {cmd} is passed to the shell, you cannot use it to append a Vim command.  See :bar.
```

But you could do something like:

```
command Asc execute ":w | ! cd %:p:h; ansible-playbook --syntax-check %"
```

Which eliminates the need to `cd` back, since only the executed shell changes directories.